# Is function name an alias for a memory of instructions?

Tags: c

consider the function

```
    int fun(){
            int I;
    }
```

Now is fun a pointer to memory or just an alias for memory location.

Comment: `fun` evaluates to a pointer pointing to the address of function `fun()`(which is the same as `&fun`)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will often just inline a simple function, so something like that might be neither.   But otherwise, it is actually a series of instructions.  for each function call, the compiler will put a series of instructions that save the current registers on the stack, then jump to the memory location corresponding to that function name, then popping any parameters into registers, and including a ret (return) call at the end which will restore the stack and pointer to the next instruction.

Comment: but printing fun and &fun is giving me a memory location

Comment: yes but what it gives you is the address where it will jump to, but that address doesn't really represent everything that the function "is".  It's like an array pointer.  It's just a pointer to one location in memory, but the array "is" actually the subsequent locations in memory.

Answer (score 1):

it's an alias, like a static array is.  It resolves to an address but unlike a pointer it does not store the address.